# Adding Language Translation to replace the Read More text in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I'm looking to translate the Read More text on a website. The website runs off of Wordpress and is using the Polylang translation plugin.

I have currently registered a string:

```
pll_register_string('post-read-more', 'Read More', 'gem-button');
```

Than in the back-end I'm translating the Read More string in French. I found the code that shows the "read" more text and the file that it's in. Here is the code that is listed:

```
<div class="post-read-more">
<?php thegem_button(array('href' => get_the_permalink(), 'style' => 'outline', 'text' => __('Read 
More', 'thegem'), 'size' => (is_sticky() && !is_paged() ? 'medium' : 'tiny')), 1); ?></div>
```

I need to echo the string that I just created and the only code I have is this:

```
<?php echo pll_e('Read More')?>
```

How do I add the echo code in the code above it to replace the 'Read More' so that it echos the translated string I've registered?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<div class="post-read-more">
<?php thegem_button(array('href' => get_the_permalink(), 'style' => 'outline', 'text' => pll_e('Read More'), 'size' => (is_sticky() && !is_paged() ? 'medium' : 'tiny')), 1); ?></div>
```

Comment: Hi George, that has been the closest to a solution so far. In my functions.php file I have this string registered:


/* Read More Language Edit*/
pll_register_string('post-read-more', 'Read More', 'thegem');
/* Read More End */


It is showing the correct text, but it is no longer styled the same and it is outside of the 'button' box/shape that is designated to go behind the text. For some reason, it works, just not styled.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Could you post here more code from your functions.php?